# Referencing Angular controller members from named / unnamed controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I decided to put this question up because I got to a point where I'm pretty confused about how *Angular* and the more delicate parts of *JavaScript* work. I try to formulate my question so it can be broken down.

1. The standard way of exposing variables from a controller is to declare them on `$scope`.

   ```
   .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.value = 5; 
   });
   ```

   Then from a template reference it like this, assuming `MyCtrl` is the controller:

   ```
   {{value}}
   ```

   When I use the controllerAs syntax, for example with `ui-router` like this:

   ```
   state('mystate', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/some.html',
     controller:  'MyCtrl as ctrl' }
   ```

   I can still get `value` with `{{value}}` so this works. However if I declare another value like this:

   ```
   .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.value = 5;
     this.otherValue = 10;
   });
   ```

   Then with `controller: 'MyCtrl'` syntax, I can **not** reference `{{otherValue}}`.
   However with the `controller: 'MyCtrl as ctrl'` syntax, I can reference them like this:

   ```
   {{value}} {{ctrl.otherValue}}
   ```

   *Summary of point 1*: I can always reference `value` like `{{value}}` but can only reference `otherValue` if the controller is named, so `{{ctrl.otherValue}}`.
2. My second point is about functions and the topic is similar to point 1. Suppose I define two functions:

   ```
   .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.myFunc = function() {};
     this.otherFunc = function () {};
   });
   ```

   Now if again as above I use the `controller: 'MyCtrl'` syntax, from the template I can call `myFunc`:

   ```
   <button ng-click="myFunc()">
   ```

   But this will **not** work:

   ```
   <button ng-click="otherFunc()">
   ```

   Now with `controller: 'MyCtrl as ctrl'` syntax, calling `myFunc` like these will **not** work:

   ```
   <button ng-click="ctrl.myFunc()">
   <button ng-click="myFunc()">
   ```

   But I can call `otherFunc` by referencing the controller with the name:

   ```
   <button ng-click="ctrl.otherFunc()">
   ```

   *Summary of point 2*: I can only call `$scope.` functions like I'm used to when I don't use the controllerAs syntax, and can only call `this.` functions when I reference the named controller.
   This is in contrast with *point 1* where I can reference the `$scope.` variable from either named or unnamed controller definition.

I know controller constructor functions are for setting up the `$scope`, and templates should use the `$scope`, but what is different about named controllers then?
I'm guessing the controllerAs syntax causes that custom name to point to not the *scope* but the controller function itself, but I would be grateful if somebody would clear this up for me.

I also think these behaviours are not related to just *ui-router* but it's generally how it works, so I would also like to know:

- What should be set on `$scope` and what shouldn't?
- What should be set on the function itself(?) and what shouldn't?
- Is there a way to access `$scope.` functions when using named controllers?
- Any advice or some obvious point I'm missing?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$scope` and the controller are two different objects. (The controller function in Angular is actually a Javascript constructor for an object, and that object is accessible as normal using `this`.) So putting something in `$scope` - `$scope.value = "xxx"` - is totally different that putting something in `this` - `this.otherValue = "yyy"`. The rule in Angular is that the `$scope` is what is accessible from view templates (i.e. the HTML), so anything under `$scope` is directly accessible with the `{{value}}` notation and template expressions.

To summarize: You cannot access members of the controller from the template just as you cannot access members of the window object (or the `$http` service, or `$q`, ..., and so on) because these are totally different objects than the `$scope`. Only members of the `$scope` are accessible from the view.

*Naming* the controller does a simple thing: the controller is placed *in the `$scope`* under the given name. Therefore the controller is accessible e.g. as `{{ctrl}}`, and its members accessible as `{{ctrl.otherValue}}`. (To make certain things are clear: executing `this.otherValue = "yyy"` in the controller makes `otherValue` a member of the controller.)

I hope this answers questions (1) and (2). For the rest:

> What should be set on `$scope` and what shouldn't?

Place in the `$scope` things that need to be accessible from the view.

> What should be set on the function itself(?) and what shouldn't?

I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you mean `this.xxx = "yyy"` in the controller, this does not place `xxx` in the function, rather in the object *constructed* by the function (`this`).

> Is there a way to access `$scope.` functions when using named controllers?

You can always access `$scope` members (functions or not). Don't get confused: In your example above, i.e. `$scope.myFunc = function() {}; this.otherFunc = function () {};`, `myFunc` is a member of the `$scope` object, not the controller, so there is no way to access it as `ctrl.myFunc()`.

> Any advice or some obvious point I'm missing?

It is not clear in simple cases that the controller is actually a constructor function called with `new` and creates a new object. This is really useful in cooperating directives, where one directive can `require` the controller of another directive it cooperates with and call controller member functions.

Comment: To add to this, my rule of thumb is to put *data* on `$scope` and *behavior* on the controller.

Comment: Thanks @Nikos, I probably was half-aware of this, just got confused because I didn't know for sure. Your answer enlightened me in a snap.

I've also found [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers/14168699#14168699).

@Jeff This is exactly what I came up with, just feels better structured somehow. Based on the linked answer one just needs to be careful not to put `this` into functions defined on `$scope` because  the closure won't work as you'd expect.

Comment: @JeffHubbard Yes, this really sums thing up well!